# How, using this code do I make it so that when a score differential is greater than blah blah blah, it says something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

```
/////
//credit to @Aditya from StackOverflow for helping me edit this code
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = data['games'];
                    console.log(text); 
                    var str = '';  
                    var textsearch = $('#text').val(); 

                    if(textsearch!=null)
                    {
                        str = '';

                        var text = data.games;
                        text = text.filter(function (game) {
                            return game.tsc !== '';
                        });

                        for (var key in text)
                        { 
                            if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts'))
                            {
                                if(text[key]['htn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                                {

                                    str= capitalize(text[key]['ts']) + ", " + text[key]['htn']+ " vs "+ text[key]['atn']+ " score : "+ text[key]['hts']+"-"+text[key]['ats']+ ";" + "\n";
                                }
                                if( text[key]['atn'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
                                    str += capitalize(text[key]['ts']) + ", " + text[key]['atn'] + " vs "+ text[key]['htn'] + " score : "+ text[key]['ats']+"-"+text[key]['hts'] + ";" + "\n";
                            }
                         }
                         console.log("str: " + str);
                        $('#result').html('<p>' + str + '</p>');
                        $('#result').css({'color': '#FF5050'}); 
                        $('#result').css({'text-align': 'center'});
                        $('#result').css({'font-size': '20px'});
                        $('#result').css({'font-family': 'Georgia'});
                    }

            }
        });

    });
});

function capitalize (str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

I have this code up there, I want so when, lets say, a team is wins by three, it says, "What a blowout!" And if a team wins by one it says something like "What a nail biter!" I want a very similar format but just instead of what is pasted to the page now, I want these phrases. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple switch statement will do the trick.

```
var output;
switch(score){//score is a variable which hold the difference
    case 1:
        output = "What a nail biter!";
        break;
    case 3:
        output = "What a blowout!";
        break;
    default:
        output = "What a match!";
}

$('#result').html('<p>' + output + '</p>');
```

Comment: How do you know a team wins by three? That variable that holds that information needs to be "switched". The output is up to you.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of confused what you are asking right now.

Comment: You are stating in your question that a team can win by three or one. I guess you know the scores somehow. The code is partially functional because the variable `score` is not defined.

Comment: Well the code I wrote pulls the score from the API http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp
Id wanna do something like var scoredifferential=hts-ats and then can you help incorporate it into what you said?

Comment: Replace `switch(score){` with `switch(scoredifferential){` and you are done :) Try to learn how to debug your code. It will help you in the long run as amateur.

Comment: thank you, when I do this where do i paste the code?

Comment: after you have created the `scoredifferential` variable and before displaying your result. If you have any more questions create a new one on StackOverflow. And if this answer answered your question you may accept it ;)

Comment: what does it need in it to be created?

Comment: Thank you. You said you "wanna do something like `var scoredifferential=hts-ats`". Thats all you need I guess. I don't have the time to spit your code and decipher your needs. It needs an number I guess.

Comment: In your success handler. I don't know what you are asking I guess.

Comment: pasted it there along with this                        
var scoredifferential = text[key]['hts'] - text[key]['ats']
and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Maybe a weird question but do you know what you are doing with `text[key]['hts']`? You need to make sure text and key are defined. There is a check in your code.. put it beneath that `if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htn') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts'))`

Comment: so what do I need to do to define scoredifferential? and once I do define it all I must do is change score in your code to scoredifferential?

Comment: 1: You defined variables with `var`. You should know that. 2: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be as simple as doing a subtraction on text[key]['hts'] - text[key]['ats'], and if the differential is plus or minus 3, append to the str variable the "what a blowout"?  What's hard for me to advise is where you wnat this tex tto show, next to the score?

Comment: Because I am an amateur programmer, I'm kinda confused, can you tell me what I need to do and where to insert it?